# Accessing the button of a WiFi-Stick (TP Link TL-WN823N)

Tags: wireless, usb, hardware

I just bought a TP Link TL-WN823N it seems to be working just fine.

It has a button on it. I would like to trigger an event when it is pressed. Any idea how I could find out anything about it (reading its status), or in the best case how to listen on it for a change?

Here you can find it's data sheet: http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=240&model=TL-WN823N

P.S.: I don't want to use it to set up WPS but a custom action (i.e. starting a shell script).

Comment: Tried xev so far, returned nothing.

Comment: Couldn't find an according device in /dev any tricks to find the device there?

Comment: with xinput i could not find anything useful too

Answer (score 1):

From the data sheet:

> **One Button Security Setup**
>
> Compatible with Wi-Fi Protected Setup™ (WPS), TL-WN823N features Quick
>   Security Setup that allows users to almost instantly setup their
>   security simply by pressing the WPS button to automatically establish
>   a WPA2 secure connection, more secure than WEP encryptions. Not only
>   is this faster than normal security setups but more convenient in that
>   users needn't remember a password!

And then please see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Setup

> A major security flaw was revealed in December 2011 that affects
>   wireless routers with the WPS PIN feature, which most recent models
>   have enabled by default. The flaw allows a remote attacker to recover
>   the WPS PIN in a few hours with a brute-force attack and, with the WPS
>   PIN, the network's WPA/WPA2 pre-shared key. Users have been urged
>   to turn off the WPS PIN feature, although this may not be possible on
>   some router models.

While it may be fun to explore the feature, it seems to make your entire network less secure than WPA2-AES.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. The thing is, I don't want to use it to set up WPS but a custom action (i.e. starting a shell script).

Comment: Without hacking the wireless driver, I am pretty sure such a thing is not possible. The driver is undoubtedly open source, so you can certainly examine it. I am uncertain that _any_ Linux wireless driver supports WPS.